# lxterminal prompt unwanted characters

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, prompt, lxterminal

I'm on fresh Lubuntu 14.04 installation. I am using LXTerminal and this is the prompt I'm setting through .bashrc file:

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m$ \w \e[m"
```

Assume I enter a command up to 15 characters long (and execute so it registers to history) (never mind "command not found"):

```
$ ~ 012345678901234
012345678901234: command not found
```

Now if I press up arrow I get my command back:

```
$ ~ 012345678901234
```

And if I press down arrow, I'm back to the bare prompt:

```
$ ~
```

**THE PROBLEM**
The problem starts if I have 16 or more characters to run:

```
$ ~ 0123456789012345
0123456789012345: command not found
```

Now when I press up arrow, I am presented with previous command just fine:

```
$ ~ 0123456789012345
```

Pressing down arrow doesn't bring me back to bare prompt, it somehow memorizes 10 characters of the first over 16-characters long command in my history and displays it until anything else is run. It basically becomes my default prompt for the time being.

```
$ ~ 0123456789
```

I can now press return to get rid of it, or I can run any other command. For the sake of example this:

```
$ ~ 0123456789ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
```

What can I do to fix it? It's not that big a deal but it's quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap colour codes in `\[` and `\]`

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]$ \w \[\e[m\]'
```

Also, PS1 is only relevant to your interactive shell, you don't need to export it to child processes.